# Custom error templates for Symfony2 exceptions

Tags: php, templates, exception, symfony

How can I customize Symfony2 exceptions (for example HTTP 404 error) templates?

I've found some material on symfony.com, but they don't work, there are some path where should lay default exception templates, but in my project there are not such directories. It seems like their documentation is outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's here:

```
app
 |- Resources
 |  | - TwigBundle
 |  |  |- view
 |  |  |  |- Exception
 |  |  |  |  |- error.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error400.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error404.html.twig
 |  |  |  |  |- error500.html.twig
 |  | - view
 |  |  |- base.html.twig
 |- config
     [...]
```

with examples of \vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources\views\Exception\error*.html.twig

Comment: the same is on symfony.com but there is no directory called `views` in `\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Resources`. But I've tried to error.html.twig file containing only word "test" in `app\Resources\TwigBundle\view\Exception` but it doesn't work, the default error template is being called

Comment: the actual error templates is placed under `\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Resources\views\Exception`, that's why I think that the documentation on symfony.com is outdated

Comment: You speak well about prod env and not dev env? This last is special.
And about your Exception directory path, if you check from the original Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.0.4.zip, you'll find the Exception directory as I wrote.

Comment: is in prod env that path different from dev env? if so, how should I use my custome templates in prod env?

Comment: No no, it's the same path, it's just that in dev env, the template which is used is exception.html.twig and not error500.html.twig & co.

Comment: but what's the explanation that in my project there aren't directories and files like you've mentioned?

Comment: and why putting files to the `app\Resources\TwigBundle\view\Exception` doesn't work?

Comment: Check if you are really in v2.0.4.
You can also have a look at in \app\cache\\[dev|prod]\templates.php for the path which has been generated for   'TwigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig' & co

Comment: definitely :) do you know any way to update without losing anything? I cannot find anything useful on the web

Answer (score -1):

To overwrite Exception template ( Exception is not an error ) this is the real template to overrite.

app > Resources > TwigBundle > views > Exception > exception.html.twig